# signer privilege escalated when trying to transfer tokens out of a PDA owned escrow wallet

Tags: anchor, token, spl-token-program

Here is the list of accounts I passed in (the `...` is extra constraints and stuff I removed for readability)

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct SendTokens<'info>  {
        #[account(mut, seeds = [...], bump)] 
        pub pda: Box<Account<'info, VmData>>,
        #[account(mut, seeds=[])],
            bump,
            token::mint=...,
            token::authority=pda,
        )]
        pub escrow_wallet: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
        #[account()]
        pub receiver_1: SystemAccount<'info>,
        #[account(mut, ...)]
        receiver_1_token_wallet: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
        #[account(mut, ...)]
        pub receiver_2: SystemAccount<'info>,
        #[account(mut]
        pub receiver_2_token_wallet: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub receiver_3_token_wallet: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
        pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    }
```

here is the instruction:

```
pub fn send_tokens(ctx: Context<SendTokens>) -> Result<()> {
    let nonce = ctx.accounts.vm_pda.nonce.to_be_bytes();
        let inner_seeds = vec![...];
        let seeds = vec![inner_seeds.as_slice()];

    let transfer_to_taker_ix = spl_token::instruction::transfer(
        &ctx.accounts.token_program.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.escrow_wallet.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.receiver_1_wallet.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.pda.key(),
        &[&ctx.accounts.pda.key()],
        1,
    )?;
    msg!("Calling the token program to transfer tokens to the taker...");
    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke_signed(
        &transfer_to_taker_ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.escrow_wallet.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.reciever_1_token_wallet.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.pda.to_account_info().clone(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info().clone(),
        ],
        &seeds,
    )?;
```

and finally, snippet of the error:

```
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account"
    
"Program log: Calling the token program to transfer tokens to the taker...", "[PDA]'s signer privilege escalated",
```

some extra information:

- the pda does have authority over the escrow_wallet (checked on solana explorer)
- I also tried to use `anchor_spl::token::Transfer` and `CpiContext::new_with_signer()` with `anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, 1)?;` (same error)
- I am able to use the `anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;` to transfer tokens from a user token wallet into a pda owned token (escrow) wallet
- there are 3 receivers because I am trying to split the tokens 3 ways, but it doesn't work even when I only have the one transfer

Comment: I"m facing the same issue, but I'm trying to use the PDA to mint a token. Just like @coco, I've logged PDA's seeds and it also brings the correct array of bytes.
Any insight on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue with the address derived from your signer seeds not matching the `pda` pubkey that's passed in from the client. Here's example working code that shows transferring spl-tokens from a token account with a PDA authority:

```
let transfer_instruction = Transfer {
    from: funds_pot.to_account_info(),
    to: destination_account.to_account_info(),
    authority: campaign.to_account_info(),
};

let campaign_seeds = &[
    b"campaign".as_ref(),
    fundstarter.key.as_ref(),
    &[campaign.bump],
];
let signer = &[&campaign_seeds[..]];

let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(token_program.to_account_info(), transfer_instruction)
    .with_signer(signer);
anchor_spl::token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount_to_withdraw)?;
```

Here `campaign` is a PDA and the authority of `funds_pot` which is a token account. That's how its seeds are used to derive a signer for the transfer instruction.

Comment: Hi! I printed out the derived address from the seeds I used with msg!(), and it matches the pda I passed in :(

Comment: Do you have a link to a github repo or somewhere else I can see the full code